# OpenGL asynchronous render of scene that takes several seconds

Tags: c++, opengl, wxwidgets

I've implemented a Mandelbrot fractal generator using wxWidgets and OpenGL. The computation is performed inside a fragment shader, and I'm using a wxGLCanvas widget to display the result. It's working well, but when I want to do a high-res export, the thread locks up for a few seconds which freezes the UI.

Initially I tried moving all rendering code (and context creation) into a separate render thread, but what I found was that it wasn't just the render thread that would lock up, but ALL threads. This could be easily demonstrated by spawning a new thread prior to doing the render that just prints a message to stdout in a loop. It would get as far as printing 1 message before freezing, then resuming once the render was complete.

To perform the file export, I first render to a texture, then I read the pixels into main memory with glGetTexImage. The render occurs asynchronously as you would expect, but the glGetTexImage function will block (again, that's expected). I therefore tried using glFenceSync in combination with glGetSynciv to only call glGetTexImage once the fence had been reached indicating a completed render.

I could confirm the draw call was returning immediately, but the moment I returned to the wxWidgets event loop to wait for the render to finish, all threads in the application would freeze. I figure maybe wxWidgets is making an OpenGL call that's forcing a sync (prob something in wxGLCanvas) - I'm fairly sure it wasn't something in my code.

I'm not sure why all threads were blocking on the glGetTexImage call, rather than just the render thread. I thought it might be a quirk of my setup (hardware, driver, OS, etc.), but got the same result on a completely different platform.

The only remaining option I can think of is to do the export render in another process with its own OpenGL context. If I'm still to use wxGLCanvas to set up the context I would probably need a visible window on the screen, which isn't ideal. Also, if the user tries to close the window during the render, it would be unresponsive.

Any ideas?

Comment: OpenGL context is unfortunately thread local, i.e. for the single thread.

Comment: Have you tried using [Pixel buffer objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object) to make the download asynchronous with respect to your GL rendering loop?

Comment: @VictorGubin: You can move OpenGL contexts between threads freely. No trouble there. The important constraint is, that a given OpenGL context can be current on only one thread at a time. But it's perfectly fine move it between threads. It's also perfectly fine, to have several contexts share their data, and each be current on a different thread, all at the same time.

Comment: @Botje That looks promising - almost like PBOs exist for this very purpose :) I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: @datenwolf  - `The important constraint is, that a given OpenGL context can be current on only one thread` I meant exactly that fact. Off cause no limitation on thread count you app using, i.e. another thread with an message only window with their own OpenGL context, can be used to background rendering of HR image into texture. In any case since OP already on the modern OpenGL, probably Vukan can be an option.

Comment: [wxVulkan](https://github.com/usingcpp/wxVulkanTutorial)

Comment: wxGLCanvas is just a this wrapper for context creation and MakeCurrent/SwapBuffers funcs which are OS calls, so wxWidgets does the specific platform code. All of OGL API is unknow to wxGLCanvas. I suspect of a CPU blocking (due to OGL driver) rather than a thread blocking. You can test this by creating a thread, make the context current inside this thread, and then begin with glGetTexImage while checking if the event loop is also frozen.

Comment: Are you sure that the threads of the application are blocked, and not the actual display update of the GPU? One solution would be to simply split your rendering in several draw calls, each updating a portion of the final image - since you do the work in the fragment shader, you just need to draw different base geometry.

Comment: @derhass I like that idea, it's very simple and (I think) guaranteed to work. I can just draw horizontal strips (perhaps individual rows) and read them into RAM one at a time. (Horizontal strips will be contiguous in memory, so no complicated stitching required.) Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You can also draw the strips separately, and read back the whole image at once. YOu probably need some bigger chunks for efficient burst transfers (but it probably will not matter that much)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so much a solution, but a workaround (suggested by derhass in the comments) is to split the render into several smaller renders. I'm drawing the image in horizontal strips, each 10 pixels high, and calling wxSafeYield() between each one so the UI remains somewhat responsive (and the user can abort the render if it's taking too long).

An additional advantage is that there's less danger of overloading the GPU. Prior to implementing this I once kicked off a long render that caused my displays to shut off and I had to do a hard reboot.